# Reason why CFS scheduler using red black tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler, red-black-tree

CFS scheduler picks next process based on minimum virtual time and to get this value efficiently its using Red-Black tree(rbtree), using rbtree we will get minimum O(h) here h is height of rbtree. But, using min-heap we can get min virtual time process in O(1) time only. I just want to know why min-heap is not consider in CFS implementation and is there any difficulties using min-heap in kernel level?

Comment: I'am not an expert in algorithms, but it seems that after o(1) peek you should perform heapify (which is o(log n)) to restore heap property. So give the reference to the implementation you talking about if I am wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is: Heaps are array based and hence require contiguous memory in kernel space. This is because the way heaps are implemented in Linux. See the files `lib/prio_heap.c` and `include/linux/prio_heap.h` and you'll note that heap is `kmalloc`'d using `heap_init`. Once the multi-programming space becomes huge, maintaining thousands of `struct sched_entity` requires lot of contiguous space (it runs in several pages). From time and performance point of view, one would prefer heap as hepify operation can run in background once min `vruntime` is picked but it's space requirement which makes bottleneck.

As `rbtree` is readily available, kernel developers didn't think of implementing pointer based heap, in fact one doesn't need.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only explanation I've found that actually gives the advantage a rbtree has over a heap. Other explanations are all saying that they share the same time complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Another interesting point is that, considering you have a task (process or thread) **changing state from runnable to blocked (waiting for io or network resource), then you need to remove that task from the runqueue** and the complexities are:

- O(log(n)) for red black tree
- O(n) for heap

**The remove operation of heap is slow and that's why red black tree is better.**

And when we get the min vruntime, the heap operation is not actually O(1), O(1) only happen if you refer the root node without removing it. But in CFS, we need to

- Remove it (which requires heapifying of O(log(n)))
- Update vruntime, and insert it back to runqueue which needs O(log(n)), too

Comment: True. This can be another possible reason!

Comment: Removing a heap node is O(log(n)) instead of O(n). Just swap the node to remove with the last element in the array, delete the element, and then heapify the swapped node.

Comment: The problem of removing is that "how do you find the node?". In a heap, there is no order inside which means you need to traverse all the node to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Also to add one point, RBTreee is CFS scheduling cache the tree.min value when updating the entity based on the `virtualruntime`, which is the process with the smallest `virtualruntime`, which in turn yields an O(1) result for picking up the next process.

pick_next_entity() -> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9de1f9c8ca5100a02a2e271bdbde36202e251b4b/kernel/sched/fair.c#L4657

pick_next_entity() -> __pick_first_entity() https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9de1f9c8ca5100a02a2e271bdbde36202e251b4b/kernel/sched/fair.c#L639

pick_next_entity() -> __pick_first_entity() -> (root)->rb_leftmost
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3bc1bc0b59d04e997db25b84babf459ca1cd80b7/include/linux/rbtree.h#L106

Scheduler can try to access the cached value from `root` of the tree.